# SELECT Last record in a Month based on Users table

Tags: sql, date

I have a table that is a collection entries with invoices based on users

```
INV_NUMBER      FK_CUST_ID  INV_DATE    FK_SALES_REP_ID 
2000000001      25416        2/25/2013     540  
2000000002      25409        3/3/2013      539  
2000000003      6107         2/16/2013     539  
2000000004      3332         2/18/2013     540  
510370000000792 43565        12/31/2013    765
```

How do I create a query that would give me the last `INV_NUMBER` in a month of December 2013
of a each `SALES_REP`.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: There is only one record in `dec`. Can there be more records?

Comment: Or you just want the latest updation?

Comment: @Tim ; Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: @G one: I want last inv_Numbr of that month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQ_Server >= 2005 you can use a common-table-expression and a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT INV_NUMBER,FK_CUST_ID,INV_DATE,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY FK_SALES_REP_ID
           ORDER BY INV_DATE DESC)
  FROM dbo.Invoices
)
SELECT INV_NUMBER FROM CTE
WHERE  RN = 1 AND MONTH(INV_DATE) = 12 AND YEAR(INV_DATE) = 2013
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3650/7/0)</kbd>

Comment: how i get result for each users

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Why can't we use just the `orderby` function and use `limit as 1` with simple select statement? Even that will give what is required...

Comment: @Gone: this approach presumes sql-server as rdbms. You cannot use a simple orderby+limit(or `TOP`) since OP wants the latest invoice for **each SALES_REP**.

Comment: if i am skipping RN = 1 , its display SALES_REP repetition

Comment: @user3292170: why do you want to omit the `RN=1`? That's the essential part of the `ROW_NUMBER` approach. If you want to get the result for every user use `PARTITION BY FK_SALES_REP_ID, FK_CUST_ID ...`. You can concat multiple  columns by which the result set is partitioned with comma, the same applies to the `ORDER BY` part.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : if i want to retrive sales_rep name and cust_name from  other table , where i can add the joins

Comment: @Salman: you can either add the joins directly in the `CTE`(you can also add `WHERE`-clauses there) or in the main query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter:Where is can add the joins in CTE

Comment: @Salman: `SELECT Columns FROM dbo.Invoices i INNER JOIN OtherTable o ON i.KeyCol=o.ForeignKeyCol`. The same way as always.

Answer (score 0):

Inv_number is consecutive? If y es then max value is the last.

```
Select a.id, max(b.inv_number) inv_number, b.inv_date
From Sales_rep a
Inner join invoices b on b.sales_rep_id = a.id and month(a.inv_date)  = 12 and year(a.inv_date) = 2013
Group by a.id
```